# How To Prevent DNU Publish From Locking Files

Tags: asp.net-core, dnu

I am consistently getting this error when doing a DNU publish

> The process cannot access the file 'C:...\bin\output\approot\packages\AutoMapper\3.3.1\AutoMapper.3.3.1.nupkg' because it is being used by another process

With nuget.exe you could use the command line options -DisableParallelProcessing to prevent things like this from happening but I can't find an equivalent in DNU.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio opened? What's the command you are running when you are getting this error?

Comment: This is when running "dnu publish" from the command line.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm bumping into the same error.  App_offline.htm is now supported in .net core, but even with app_offline in place, and even with my website returning a 503 error, I'm _still_ unable to replace mywebsite.exe because it's in use.  :(

Comment: I didn't really come up with a solution, just a workaround for our build process.  One the build server, I check $lastexitcode to see if there was an error during the dnu publish and trying again if there was.  Sometimes it will take 3 or 4 attempts before once succeeds.  It's not great but it works.